# change WPF user controls visibility from a login user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created an application with WPF and C# (no MVVM), I have 3 user controls containing grids, forms and others things. but finaly I wanted to add a login user control (each user control is standalone), the way I started to build it, is to set by default all the user controls visibility in xaml to collapsed except for the login usercontrol which will be collapsed after a successful login :

```
 public static DependencyProperty WindowVisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("WindowVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(MemberStats), null);

public Visibility WindowVisibility
{
    get
    {
        return (Visibility)GetValue(WindowVisibilityProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(WindowVisibilityProperty, value);
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to use Dependency proprety for multiple in the xaml of the user controls,a simple way with explanation or any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Look [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140620/WPF-Tutorial-Dependency-Property)

Comment: Well If you use all the usercontrols in the same mainwindow just use the parent property, to get access to the mainwindow and then you should be able to change any usercontrol you want.. in code..

Answer (score 0):

In the window tag add  x:Name="SomeName".

Then bind to the local property like this.

Visibility="{Binding WindowVisibility, ElementName=SomeName}"

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I've tested it in a usercontrol but but how can I change the visibility after the login ?